# How can there be a name before a class name?

Tags: visual-c++, ogre

```
#ifndef __DynTex_H__
#define __DynTex_H__

#include "SdkSample.h"

using namespace Ogre;
using namespace OgreBites;

class _OgreSampleClassExport Sample_DynTex : public SdkSample
{
public:

    Sample_DynTex() : TEXTURE_SIZE(128), SQR_BRUSH_RADIUS(Math::Sqr(12))
    {
```

The class name is `Sample_DynTex`, as you can see from the constructor name. But how is `_OgreSampleClassExport` a valid syntax? What does it mean to have `_OgreSampleClassExport`? I couldn't even find a file with that name in the Ogre source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_OgreSampleClassExport` is almost certainly defined in a header along with it's import counterpart:

```
#define _OgreSampleClassExport __declspec(dllexport)
#define _OgreSampleClassImport __declspec(dllimport)
```